# Bus error 10 on trying to get the value of a vector iterator

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

This is the code I'm using to build a Linked List.

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;

};


Node* buildList(vector<int> &useThisVectorToBuildList)
{
    Node *newNode, *head, *tail;
   // vector<int> populateList(10,2,2,1,2,4,5);
    int vdata;
    for(vector<int>::iterator vecItr = useThisVectorToBuildList.begin(); vecItr!=useThisVectorToBuildList.end() ; vecItr++)
    {
        vdata = *vecItr;

        //create new node
        newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = vdata;
        newNode->next = nullptr;

        // if first node - head - hasn't been created yet
        if(head==nullptr){
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail       = newNode;
        }

    }

    return head;
}
```

Here's what my main looks like (I'm just trying to print out the head node's data value):

```
/* ---------------------------- MAIN --------------------------------------- */
int main()
{
    vector<int> populateList{1,2,3,3,1,24,5};
    Node *listHead = buildList(populateList);

    cout << listHead->data  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be a lack of understanding as to how iterators work.
With this code, when I execute the code, I get a "bus error: 10".

**However**
If I change the existing code slightly (I'm showing only the changes below):

```
Node* buildList(vector<int> &useThisVectorToBuildList)
{
   ...
    for(vector<int>::iterator vecItr = useThisVectorToBuildList.begin(); vecItr!=useThisVectorToBuildList.end() ; vecItr++)
    {
        vdata = *vecItr;
        cout << vdata << endl; // ADDED THIS LINE TO DEBUG and print value.

        //create new node
        newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = *vecItr;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
       ...
    }
    return head;
}
```

I get the output:

```
1
Segmentation fault: 11
```

**And**, if I change like so:

```
Node* buildList(vector<int> &useThisVectorToBuildList)
{
    Node *newNode, *head, *tail;

    for(vector<int>::iterator vecItr = useThisVectorToBuildList.begin(); vecItr!=useThisVectorToBuildList.end() ; vecItr++)
    {

        cout << *vecItr << endl; // ADDED THIS TO DEBUG. NOTE LACK OF TEMP VARIABLE "int vdata"

        //create new node
        newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = *vecItr;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    ...
    }
    return head;
}
```

I get proper output.

```
1
2
3
3
1
24
5


1
```

***Why am I seeing proper output by merely printing out the values iterator points to before assigning the value to a variable?***

Comment: Your compiler should warn you about uninitialized variables _and you should read and fix this warning_.

Comment: g++ on OSX didn't give any warnings :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never let variables unitialized. In your program, you are having an undefined behaviour.

Look at here:

```
Node *newNode, *head, *tail; // Unitialized pointers

[...]


// if first node - head - hasn't been created yet
if(head==nullptr){  // Which is the value of head? Unitiliazed, but probably different of nullptr
    head = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
}
else{
    tail->next = newNode;  // Using tail (which is unitialized) 
    tail       = newNode;
}
```